# Connecting water to outside hose bibb

Tags: water

My house is missing a hose bibb at the front of the house, there are two all the way in the back of the house. To get water to the front of the house (for watering my lawn and washing my car), I have two garden hoses connected to the back to the front. Now I'm thinking of installing a hose bibb on the front of the house. I have existing 3/4" PVC pipe to the front of the house from the old HVAC. In the picture below is the pipe, lower right. It's been cut off when they installed my new HVAC:

[image]

This pipe connects to the outside. Originally this pipe removed water from the old HVAC:

[image]

Here's the water supply:

[image]

I was thinking to connect a water supply valve to the cut off pipe in the first image. Then running the line to the water supply at the top of the water heater (which goes out to the sprinkler system, also broken). Can any one please give me some advice about how to connect the pipe to the water supply. Thanks.

Comment: That pipe that you have placed in the lower red rectangle of the third picture is a natural gas pipe - not a water pipe.

Comment: The wall in the first photo, with the short bit of pipe highlighted. Is that an exterior wall?

Comment: It is the wall to the garage. The pipe runs through the garage.

Answer (score 1):

That old PVC pipe is highly unlikely to be up to code for carrying a pressurized water distribution line.

You also do not want to place water service outside like that because it will freeze and burst the pipes when it gets cold in winter (unless you live in an Amazon tropical zone or Hawaii).

Proper installation is to install it inside near to the heated space of the home. Use of copper or PEX would be the preferred material for the water lines. If you use PVC makes sure that it is a proper type for pressurized water service.

Comment: "That old PVC pipe" is very likely perfectly normal code-compliant schedule 40 PVC, rated for well over 100PSI in cold water service. SDR is not too common that small. If drained before winter it would be fine.

Comment: Use of a [self draining faucet](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/how-to/intro/0,,480863,00.html) will preclude draining, as well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Maybe SCH-40 pipe but a friend of mine just had two separate instances in a house he recently purchased where such pipe was used for feeding into a bathroom from a garage. (previous owner remodel) He had pipes break right off when things fell on them from a few feet height. PVC can get brittle and susceptible to problems like this.